# NGINX switch root by path param and run for angular project

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to change the root directory by first URL path param.

The example URL is: `https://example-domain.com/uuid_1/product/list?mode=card`

Expected behaviour is that the root should be switched to path param of `uuid_1`. And rest path (`/product/list?mode=card`) should be run for the angular project.

**I need the nginx config for this situation. I tried some config but failed.**

---

**Success Scenerios**

```
Example 1:

URL: https://example-domain.com/uuid_1

THEN:
root => /main_folder/uuid_1/angular/dist
run for angular => /
```

```
Example 2:

URL: https://example-domain.com/uuid_2/product/list?mode=card

THEN:
root => /main_folder/uuid_2/angular/dist
run for angular => /product/list?mode=card
```

```
Example 3:

URL: https://example-domain.com/uuid_3/product/edit?id=abc

THEN:
root => /main_folder/uuid_3/angular/dist
run for angular => /product/edit?id=abc
```

---

**Server Folder Hierarchy**

```
- main_folder
  - uuid_1
    - angular_project_dist
      - index.html
      - ...(rest_of_files_of_angular_project) 
  - uuid_2
    - angular_project_dist
      - index.html
      - ...(rest_of_files_of_angular_project) 
  - uuid_3
    - angular_project_dist
      - index.html
      - ...(rest_of_files_of_angular_project) 
  - uuid_4
    - angular_project_dist
      - index.html
      - ...(rest_of_files_of_angular_project)
```

---

**Failed NGINX config:**

```
server {

    server_name example-domain.com;

    index index.html index.htm;

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {

        if ($uri ~* /([^/]+)/(.*)){
            set $project_id $1;
            set $rest_of_uri /$2;
        }
        root /var/www/example-domain.com/$project_id/angular/dist/;
        try_files $rest_of_uri $rest_of_uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `if...set` block, you could use a regular expression location with named captures to create the variables.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(?<project_id>[^/]+)(?<rest_of_uri>/.*)$ {
    root /var/www/example-domain.com/$project_id/angular/dist/;
    try_files $rest_of_uri $rest_of_uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

If you want to find `index.html` within this location you will need to add `=404` to the end of the `try_files` statement, otherwise Nginx will treat it as a redirect and search for another location to process the request. See [`try_files` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).